# Magento 2 : How to add new section in product page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-attribute

[image]

In the above image, I want to add a section like content, configuration, product reviews etc. How can i do it?

And I also want to add my custom drop drop attribute inside the section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for coding. **Magento provides the feature to add such new sections by default.**

You just need to follow below steps:

- Login to admin panel and go to **Stores** -> **Attributes** (**Attribute Set**).
- Click on the attribute set in which you want to add the section.
- Under **Groups**, click on **Add New** button. A new popup window will open. Fill the **group name** and click on **OK** button.

[image: Click on Add New button]
[image: Popup]

This will add the section.

Now, to change the position of the newly added section, you can drag and drop up and down and put it to the desired location.

To add attributes under this section, simply drag the attribute under the section.

Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes you are right. No need to write hassle code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can create you own module.

In this module, create a file called `view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xm`l with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Welcome" name="product.welcome" as="custom-tab" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Welcome</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
    </page>
```

In block `Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Welcome.ph`p put below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Welcome extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml';

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

In templates `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/welcome.phtml` put below code.

```
<div class="welcome">
    <?php echo __('Welcome !'); ?>
</div>
```

Now Check Product edit page. It's working perfect.

Comment: No it's not working

Answer (score 0):

create uicomponent form xml Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml put below code.
For 2.2.0 and above it's in UI component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="testingproduct">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Testing Group</item>
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.product</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">product_form</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="testing_group">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\CustomData</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```